# React-beautiful-dnd: How to drag one element from a different DragDropContext to another DragDropContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I want to move one element from a different `DragDropContext` to another:

I have a:
// sidebar.js

```
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={() => console.log('sidebar end drag')}>

    <Droppable droppableId="sidebar">
       {provided => 
        <Draggable 
           ref={provided.innerRef} 
           {...provided.draggableProps} 
           {...other props}
         >
           I can be dragged
         </Draggable>
       }
    </Droppable>

</DragDropContext >
```

// footerDroppable.js

```
    <Droppable droppableId="footerDrop">
       {provided => 
        <Draggable 
           ref={provided.innerRef} 
           {...provided.draggableProps} 
           {...other props}
         >
           I'm a footer drag
         </Draggable>
       }
    </Droppable>

</DragDropContext >
```

// the structure

```
<div>
  <Sidebar> // first drag context
  <div>
    <footer>
       <other elements />
       <FooterDroppable /> // second drag context
    <footer>
  <div/>
```

can I move the draggable elemtn from the footer to the sidebar / vice versa?

Sure I can just move the `DragDropContext` on the parent of both components (which I know how to do) but **ARE THERE OTHER WAY** aside from having a one parent `DragDropContext`??

P.S. the code above are not the exact structure/code but more like a prototype so you can visualize since I'm working on a bigger app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated, you can have a single `DragDropContext` to handle d'n'd between multiple `Droppable`.

And there's no other way to do it (right now) with `react-beautiful-dnd`.

Comment: Has something been improved since? I need this functionality...

Comment: It goes against the design of the library, so I don't think it will ever happen.

Comment: Sorry for being late, after your comment I remembered how I managed it, even docs say [It is advised to just wrap your entire application in a <DragDropContext />](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/api/drag-drop-context.md). That being said, I simply put Droppable wherever I want and you can just drag and drop anywhere, doesn't matter where your Droppable is located at in DOM.

Comment: Well at least it was ok for my use case. Doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this option out https://react-beautiful-dnd.netlify.app/?path=/story/multiple-horizontal-lists--stress-test from beautiful-dnd

Comment: this doesn't answer the question as the example above shares the same `DragDropContext` parent